# Add listener to JPanel that will be only called onload

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Well the question is pretty straight forward:

In C# WinForms you got a listener on the Winform called onload > [onload winforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). 
This is what I also want to create in my JPanels, because I want to fill my JList with data from the database.

I tried using the MouseMotionListener but then I need a Timer which controls the select statement to the database, otherwise he would spam the database with the select statement.

I got this code to switch panels:

```
public void changePanel(String panelRef) {
    ((CardLayout) (getContentPane().getLayout())).show(getContentPane(), panelRef);
}
```

The panels are instantiated and added in the JFrame.

Comment: I'm not sure about others, but for me it would help if you provided more detail, context and code. For istance, when is the JPanel "loaded"? Does an event initiate this event? Are you swapping views for example with a CardLayout?

Comment: It depends, Java doesn't have a concept "load". You could use the constructor, or provide your own "load" method which you could call when you want to perform the load action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you are using a CardLayout and you want to know when a card is made visible. You can use a HierarchyListener on your panel.

The basic code to listen for the panel becoming visible would be:

```
@Override
public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent e)
{
    JComponent component = (JComponent)e.getSource();

    if ((HierarchyEvent.SHOWING_CHANGED & e.getChangeFlags()) != 0
    &&  component.isShowing())
    {
        // add code here
    }
}
```

FWIW, this approach is used in [Card Layout Focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/card-layout-focus/) which is an extension to `CardLayout` that provides additional functionality when a card becomes active.

Answer (score 2):

Try `ComponentListener` as work around:

```
panel.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    boolean loaded = false;
    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent ce) {
        if(loaded) {
          return;
        }
        loaded = true;
        //to do here
    }
});
```